# Django Form not rendering in template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I must just be overlooking something here, but after stripping everything back - I can't seem to get Django to render either a Form or ModelForm to my template. Code below:

```
#forms.py
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
   subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   message = forms.CharField()
   sender = forms.EmailField()
   cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

#views.py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form
    return render_to_response('home/new_website.html',{
        'form': form,
        })

#new_website_html
<html>
<body>
    <form method = "post" action = "">
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: What is the exact problem. The template is blank? No form fields?

Comment: try `return render_to_response('home/new_website.html',{
        'form': form,
        }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))`

Comment: plus tell us the error which help us to identify the problem.

Comment: There is no error being output. The {{ form }} just generate the modelform like it has previously. Going by @linpingta comment, I might need to dig deeper and see if there's an underlying issue or conflict somewhere perhaps. I thought I may have just been overlooking code.

Comment: Also - I have tried the context_instance line, I think I read another stackoverflow question that thad that as an answer. It was after that not working that I posted this question.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - the exact problem is that the {{ form }} line does not generate the expected HTML form. I have tried variations of this, such as {{ form.as_p }} as well as even trying to return {{ form.<field_name} }} with no luck

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after many tries this is my solution:

Change the view from this

```
#views.py
else:
    form = ContactForm() # An unbound form
return render_to_response('home/new_website.html',{
    'form': form,
    })
```

To that:

```
#views.py
else:
    form = ContactForm() # An unbound form
    return render_to_response('home/new_website.html',{
        'form': form,
        })
```

Or a simple newline is enough:

```
#views.py
else:
    form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

return render_to_response('home/new_website.html',{
    'form': form,
    })
```

Strange thing is, after these changes the original code worked.

Answer (score 0):

Any error page or just blank page?  Actually I just try your code and get form rendering correct(I don't know how to insert local result image here)
Please make sure DEBUG=TRUE in settings.py while it's not the problem.
@Burhan I think indent problem only happens because he edits it in stackoverflow.
Btw, your form doesn't have a submit button, maybe add it in html like

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. I do have debug = true set in my code, and have several other modelforms working successfully. I'm at a loss to why this isn't working. In answer to your question, there is no error page, the HTML renders everything accept for the {{ form }} output.

Comment: Just a bit past 10 years later and this is still happening in Django with not many answers as to why on SO.

Comment: thanks for let me know I have an answer for 10 years, how time fly